# Retrieving CheckedListBox Selected Items as Dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary, checkedlistbox

I have a checkedlistbox on my form which I populate using a Dictionary. It works fine when I populate the box but when I try to retrieve the selected object I can't figure out how to do it as a dictionary.

My code to populate it:

```
reader = widgetSelection.ExecuteReader();
while (reader.Read())
{
 widgets.Add(reader.GetInt32(0), reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("name")));
}

foreach (var widget in widgets)
{
    chbWidgets.Items.Add(widget);
}
```

It populates perfectly but any attempt to do a foreach or anything out of it will only come back as object and I can't figure out the proper way to cast the items. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `widgets` in your example is a `Dictionary<int, string>`, then `chbWidgets.Items.Add(widget)` is adding a `KeyValuePair<int, string>` to the `Items` collection. To get the selected items, you can probably use `chbWidgets.CheckedItems.Cast<KeyValuePair<int, string>>()`.